# Google Search Parameters to Speak Out Results (tts)

Tags: url, search, text-to-speech, url-parameters

I am trying to automate my tasks on my Ubuntu.

What is the Google search parameter to speak out the results.

For example, When i search Donald Trumph from my voice (through microphone on Chrome)
then google speaks out "Donald Trump is 45th president of US ...."

Currently I know that the following string will show search result of Donald Truph:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=Donald+Trump
```

**What should I add to speak out the results?**

Answer (score 2):

The magic URL parameter is "**gs_ivs=1**". If this is appended to the search URL then it will speak the result.

In your case: https://www.google.be/search?q=Donald+Trump&gs_ivs=1

Test it for yourself but it works.

Got it from here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=435385

**Edit 1st March 2019 (It appears to work again)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://www.google.com/search?inm=vs&q=Donald+Trump

Adding **inm=vs** to the url will make Google search use tts if it has something to say.